# AngularJS "TypeError: Cannot read property 'protocol' of undefined" When get post data from web service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http

I'm trying to get data from web service. Here my code.

```
$scope.savePricing = function(){
        var pricing = {
          "PricingSchemeId": 0,
          "Name": $scope.name,
          "LastUserName": "Tan",
          "LastModifiedDate": "",
          "IsActive": true,
          "CurrencyId": $scope.selectedCurrency.CurrencyId,
        }
            $http({
                url: config.addPricing,
                data: pricing,
                method: "POST"
            }).success(function(data){
                alert("Success");
            }).error(function(data){
                alert("Failed");
            });
    })
```

But when i run this function, this error is shown:
[image]

What can i do now?

Comment: could you do `console.log(config.addPricing)` & see what it is, there must be you are missing protocol in your url, like it should be `http://` or `https://` at the starting of your url

Comment: Thanks, my config.addPricing is undefined. I 'll fix that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`config.addPricing` is undefined. I can easily reproduce that error as follows:

`index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="Foo">
  <head>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="my-angular.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="SomeCtrl">
    <button ng-click="go()">Go</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

`my-angular.js`:

```
var app = angular.module("Foo", []);
app.controller("SomeCtrl", function($scope, $http) {
  var config = {}; // Note the lack of "url" field.
  $scope.go = function() {
    $http({
      url: config.url, // undefined
      data: {},
      method: "POST"
    }).success(function(data) {
      console.log("Success: data", data);
    }).error(function(data) {
      console.log("Error: data", data);
    });
  };
});
```